# TCR 2.1.1 importing ITM reports

Tags: reporting, monitoring, tivoli, agents

I am trying to run some reports in TCR I imported from the 6.2.3-TIV-ITM_TMV-Agent-Reports-FP0001

Seeing that I get this error: UDA-SQL-0196 The table or view "KSY_SUMMARIZATION_CONFIG_DV" was not found in the dictionary. 
I checked and the table is not in the database.
Seeing that regarding that table it says this:

The Summarization and Pruning configuration is shown in a specific query subject (Summarization and Pruning Configuration). The result is one row that represents the most recent entry in the KSY_SUMMARIZATION_CONFIG_DV view.

Maybe the WAREHOUS is lacking something? If the agents are running shouldn't there be a view named KSY_SUMMARIZATION_CONFIG_DV?
I don't seem to find other tables like: KLZ_CPU_HV, KLZ_CPU_DV, KLZ_CPU_WV, KLZ_CPU_MV,
KLZ_CPU_QV, KLZ_CPU_YV

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure historical collection for the appropriate agent attribute groups for those tables to show up in your TDW.  For instance create a historical collection for the "Linux CPU" attribute group to get the KLZ_CPU table.  For tables ending in _D, _H, etc, configure hourly, daily, etc, summarization for those attribute groups.

Depending on collection intervals eventually the warehouse proxy agent will create the necessary tables.